# In python how can I find all the values in an array that are in between two specific values

Tags: python, arrays, loops, find

Hi I would like to go all over certain values of an array lets say

```
spikeTimes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
stimTimes =[0.5, 4.5, 7.5]
WIN_SIZE=2
```

I want for every element of `stimTimes` to be able to get the values that are in between `stimTimes[indx]` to `stimTimes[indx]+WIN_SIZE`

I should be able to get for the first value of spikeTimes(0.5) - 1,2  (between 0.5-2.5)
for the second value(4.5) - 5,6 (values that are between 4.5- 4.5+WIN_SIZE=6.5)
and for the 3rd value(7.5) - 8

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: @idjaw Maybe he's writing it in the form of an SQL query ;).

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Maybe I should add the sql tag :P

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with *nested list comprehensions*:

```
spikeTimes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

stimTimes = [0.5, 4.5, 7.5]

WIN_SIZE = 2

partitions = [[spike for spike in spikeTimes if stim <= spike <= stim + WIN_SIZE] for stim in stimTimes]

print(partitions)
```

Produces:

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6], [8]]
```